# whether ajax post method can pass two value to a php file or not?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

for example, I wanna pass two values to a php file using ajax in javascript:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"h.php",
  dataType:"text",
  data:data1,data2,
  success:funtion(response){
    $("#test").html(response);
  }
  error:function(response){
  $("#test").html(response);
  }
});
```

furthermore, h.php will connect with database and insert two values into database,plz give me a correct example. thanks

Comment: [Read the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or any of the other online resources. tl;dr use something like `data:{key1: data1, key2: data2}`

Comment: I write down code as below:      jQuery.ajax({type:"POST",url:"h.php",dataType:"text",data:{id:id,class:class},success:function(){$(#tip).html("sucess");},error:function(){$(#tip).html("fail");}});         however,it always display "fail" when I run this. I don't know the reason why I cannot connect to the database. plz help me

Comment: but I copy the codes which connect to database from h.php and save those code as a single php file. then, I test it and it is definitely connected with database.Thus, I guess probably i got something wrong with the javascript part. by the way, I use JBOSS tools (cordova phone emulator) test phone program in zend studio.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass multiple values using ajax post method like below

data: {
       id: id,
       name: name,
       class:class
      },